# Proper way to complete a non-blocking RESTful API request in PySide6?

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

I was curious as to what the proper way to complete an asynchronous HTTP request in PySide6 is. [The PySide6 documentation has this page](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager.html?highlight=qnetworkaccessmanager#PySide6.QtNetwork.PySide6.QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager) with a C++ example (which doesn't make sense, I've already tried contacting the Qt Company about it). I've tried this before but can't figure out how to get it working outside of my `QMainWindow`.

Comment: @alexpdev Actually, I think the OP does have a point. The PySide examples on that page are rather superficial and incomplete translations of the C++ originals, which seem to have been produced by some automated process.

Comment: For complete, working PySide6 examples go the [github project](https://github.com/qtproject/pyside-pyside-setup/tree/dev/examples). The [downloader example](https://github.com/qtproject/pyside-pyside-setup/blob/dev/examples/network/downloader/downloader.py) shows some basic `QNetworkAccessManager` usage.